# DTOs in a WCF Web Api project

Tags: entity-framework, dto, wcf-web-api

Ive been reading on some best practices for exposing Data over WCF Web Api and in many places it seems to be recommended not to use Domain Entities to expose your data but to use DTO for this.

What I cant find is a sample on the web on how to approach doing this.

Where can I find some documentation/samples on this?

whats your take on this approach?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [Samuel Meachan's](http://samscode.com/index.php/2010/06/entity-framework-v4-end-to-end-application-strategy-part-1-intro/) approach.